# Understanding hybrid OpenMP / MPI parallelization (using Slurm)

Tags: mpi, openmp, hpc, slurm

I have a hard time understanding the behavior of an application that I need to parallelize in a hybrid way using MPI and OpenMP. As job scheduler I use slurm.

For example I have a computational domain that is decomposed into n = nx * ny * nz parts. For my current setup this would be 4 * 1 * 2 = 8. Now in my run.sh script I set:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
```

However I also want to use OpenMP. I have 16 cores per processor and I was told to use this value. So I add:

```
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
```

Or, in one line:

```
#SBATCH -n 8 -c 16
```

If I write out some parameters I see:

```
$SLURM_NTASKS = 8
$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK = 16
```

However, the application I run always tells me that I am using a different number of tasks and threads than can be seen above. Therefore, I have several questions:

1) Do I have to set OMP_NUM_THREADS additionally or is that taken care of automatically? I would have realized that for example as:

```
if [ -n "$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK" ]; then                         
  omp_threads=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK                           
else                                                           
  omp_threads=1                                              
fi                                                           
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$omp_threads
```

2) What is the decisive parameter telling me the number of CPUs per task? SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK or OMP_NUM_THREADS?

3) I run my shell script using sbatch, and within the script I use srun for the binary. Does it make any difference whether I use srun, mpirun or mpiexec?

4) Since using srun instead of mpiexec, the outputs are written to my logfile multiple times. For example, if I use 8 MPI tasks, I get the same line 8 times. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: which MPI library (vendor & version) are you running? what does `srun --mpi=list` says? assuming you have the right support in your MPI library (PMI1, PMI2 or PMIx), `srun` is likely the way to go.

Comment: ```srun --mpi=list``` gives me: srun: ```MPI types are...
srun: none
srun: pmi2
srun: openmpi```